# How can I write faster JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I'm writing an HTML5 canvas visualization. According to the Chrome Developer Tools profiler, 90% of the work is being done in `(program)`, which I assume is the V8 interpreter at work calling functions and switching contexts and whatnot.

Other than logic optimizations (e.g., only redrawing parts of the visualization that have changed), what can I do to optimize the CPU usage of my JavaScript? I'm willing to sacrifice some amount of readability and extensibility for performance. Is there a big list I'm missing because my Google skills suck? I have some ideas but I'm not sure if they're worth it:

- Limit function calls
- When possible, use arrays instead of objects and properties
- Use variables for math operation results as much as possible
- Cache common math operations such as `Math.PI / 180`
- Use `sin` and `cos` approximation functions instead of `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()`
- Reuse objects when passing around data instead of creating new ones
- Replace `Math.abs()` with `~~`
- Study [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/) until my eyes bleed
- Use a preprocessor on my JavaScript to do some of the above operations

**Update post-closure:** Here are answers to what I thought I was asking. I'd like to add an answer to my own question with the following:

- [Efficient JavaScript - Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript)
- [JavaScript Call Performance – Just Inline It](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/01/javascript-call-performance-just-inline-it/)
- [“I want to optimize my JS application on V8” checklist](http://blog.mrale.ph/post/14403172501/simple-optimization-checklist)

Comment: Do you perceive your app as being too slow?

Comment: voted to close this. There are entire books out there about the topic, what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: `~~` is not a suitable replacement for `Math.abs()`.

Comment: Performance tuning is ALWAYS about learning how to measure what parts of your code are taking the most time.  Trying to apply performance optimizations without knowing exactly which parts of your code are the real bottlenecks is like shooting a basket blindfolded.  You might get lucky and find the right shot, but chances are you will just spend a lot of time and not make any progress.  You have to find a way to instrument your code and isolate the functions that are taking the most time.  Then, and only then, can you intelligently discuss what could be done to speed up those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Measure your performance, find the bottlenecks, then apply the appropriate techniques to help your specific bottlenecks. Premature optimization is fruitless and should be avoided at all costs.

**Mind your DOM**
 – Limit repaint/reflow

**Mind your recursion**
 – Consider iteration or memoization

**Mind your loops**
 – Keep small, sprinkle setTimeout() liberally if needed

**Loops**:

- Decrease amount of work per iteration
- Decrease number of iterations

**DOM**:

- Minimize property access - Cache DOM accessors/objects in local variables before performing operations - especially before loops.
- If you need to access items in order frequently, copy into a regular array

**Style Property**:

- Minimize changes on style property
- Define CSS class with all changes and just change **className** property
- Set **cssText** on the element directly
- Group CSS changes to minimize repaint/reflow

**String Matching**:

- If searching for simple string matches, `indexOf` should be used instead of regular expression matching wherever possible.
- Reduce the number of replace commands you use, and try to optimise into fewer, more efficient replace commands

**eval is evil**:

The 'eval' method, and related constructs such as 'new Function', are extremely wasteful. They effectively require the browser to create an entirely new scripting environment (just like creating a new web page), import all variables from the current scope, execute the script, collect the garbage, and export the variables back into the original environment. Additionally, the code cannot be cached for optimisation purposes. eval and its relatives should be avoided if at all possible.

**Only listen to what you need**:

Adding an event listener for the `BeforeEvent` event is the most wasteful of all, since it causes all possible events to fire, even if they are not needed. In general, this can be several thousand events per second. `BeforeEvent` should be avoided at all costs, and replaced with the appropriate `BeforeEvent.eventtype`. Duplicate listeners can usually be replaced with a single listener that provides the functionality of several listener functions.

**Timers take too much time**:

Because a timer normally has to evaluate the given code in the same way as eval, it is best to have as little code as possible inside the evaluated statement. Instead of writing all of the code inside the timeout statement, put it in a separate function, and call the function from the timeout statement. This allows you to use the direct function reference instead of an evaluated string. As well as removing the inefficiency of eval, this will also help to prevent creating global variables within the evaluated code.

Comment: One day I will find the person that started the practice of putting those explanatory cations on "demotivational" posters... and I will enact  my revenge.

Comment: Scrolling past that image at just the right speed kinda makes it animate :)